# Codeigniter Column 'idimport_database' in where clause is ambiguous

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having trouble when I want to display data using codeigniter, please help.
I attach the code.

Controller :

```
public function views($idimport_database)
{
    $data['title']=$idimport_database;
    $data['header']=$this->m_transaction->detail_transaction($idimport_database)->row_array();
    $data['detail']=$this->m_transaction->detail_transaction($idimport_database)->result();
    $this->template->load('template','view_data', $data);
}
```

Model :

```
function detail_transaction($idimport_database){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_import_database');
    $this->db->where('idimport_database', $idimport_database);
    $this->db->join('tbl_transaksi', 'tbl_transaksi.idimport_database = tbl_import_database.idimport_database');
    return $this->db->get();
}
```

Here result error :

```
Error Number: 1052
Column 'idimport_database' in where clause is ambiguous
SELECT * FROM `tbl_import_database` JOIN `tbl_transaksi` ON `tbl_transaksi`.`idimport_database` = `tbl_import_database`.`idimport_database` WHERE `idimport_database` = '41' Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/apriori/system/database/DB_driver.php  
Line Number: 691
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means both tables (`tbl_import_database` and `tbl_transaksi`) have a column named `idimport_database`, and MySQL does not know which one you intend to use in your where statement.

Change the function in your model to include the table name:

```
$this->db->where('tbl_import_database.idimport_database', $idimport_database);
```